# Display all labels on X axis in Chart.js regardless of whether there is data or not

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am new to Chart.js , I have been looking for a way to display all labels in chart.js regardless of whether there is a data for the label or not, I have tried the max and min but it does not work so I came across the ticks callback:

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
let config = {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "cost of goods sold",
        data: [0, 20, 40, 50],
      },
    ],
    //labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April"],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          callback: (value, index, ticks) => {
            const x = [
              "January",
              "February",
              "March",
              "April",
              "May",
              "June",
              "July",
              "August",
              "September",
              "october",
              "November",
              "December",
            ];
            return x;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

let chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

but it didnt work.
is there a way to all display a fixed label like always show 12 month, 31 days, 12 weeks

Answer (score 2):

You can define `data.labels` and make sure that `data.datasets.data` has the same number of entries, `null` for missing values.

```js
let config = {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "october", "November", "December"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "cost of goods sold",
      data: [0, 20, 40, 50, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
    }]
  }
};

new Chart('chart', config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```